# People check-in Dataset

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I am looking for people's check-in data, whether it's google history location dataset or Foursquare check-in dataset. Would you please let me know where can I find similar datasets ?

Apparently a lot of interesting studies have been going around academia but I couldn't find anything to download.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a Gowalla dataset at [SNAP repository](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/)

**https://snap.stanford.edu/data/loc-gowalla.html**

> [Gowalla](http://www.gowalla.com/) is a location-based social networking website where users share their locations by checking-in. The friendship network is undirected and was collected using their public API, and consists of 196,591 nodes and 950,327 edges. We have collected a total of 6,442,890 check-ins of these users over the period of Feb. 2009 - Oct. 2010.